# Do I need loans for a good credit score?

Tags: loans, credit-score, australia

I've never required legal loans from banks/businesses (eg: home loan, car loan)

Will this affect my credit score if i've never been in debt but later on in life decide to get a loan?

Edit:

Also, Is it worth getting a loan for no reason to improve credit score?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: It might be worth reopening the question if the answer is substantially different in Australia.